# remember username and password checkbox

Tags: java, android-studio

I have this Javascript code for login in my app. it working fine but how can I add a checkbox for remember username and password to this code to my project? Is there some one out there that can help me? Thanks for all help

```
package no.vfk.vfkhakkespettboka;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login_backup extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText Name;
    private EditText Password;
    private TextView Info;
    private Button Login;
    private int counter = 6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        Info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
        Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        Info.setText("No attempt remains: 6");

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                validate(Name.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void validate(String userName, String userPassword){
        if((userName.equals("test")) && (userPassword.equals("test123"))){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login_backup.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            counter--;

            Info.setText("No attempt remains: " + String.valueOf(counter));

            if(counter == 0){
                Login.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: javascript?....

Comment: yes it is Javascript

Comment: seems to be java, not javascript.... you know that javascript and java are very different right?

Comment: not mutch am new at it

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Java-and-JavaScript.
Pretty sure your code is Java. adjust the tags after read that link

Comment: i just followed a tutorial on youtube for making this but i try to find how to add a checkbox to remember username and password

Comment: Like @CalvinNunes: Your code 101% is Java not Javascript.  You need to learn about Java first then you can jump to Android tutorial. You can start from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui